# Pythagorean theorem vs an equation of a circle?

Tags: circles, pythagorean-triples

Today I told my teacher that the equation of a circle looks like to the Pythagorean theorem to me, but he said that I'm wrong and to re think it.

Why $(x-h)^2 + (y-k)^2 = r^2$ is not a PT, it looks just like PT -- we square two numbers, add them and we get another number squared.

Where $(h,k)$ is the center and $r$ is the radius of a circle.

Can someone explain in more details?

Comment: I would completely agree with *you* (although it's impossible to know what you actually said or what your teacher actually heard).

Comment: It *is* the pythagorean theorem.  [This picture](http://www.contracosta.edu/legacycontent/math/circle6.gif) shows that.

Comment: What!?!?!?!?  The equation of the circle has *everything* and is *utterly* and completely derived from the Pythagorean theorem.  It *looks* like the pythagorean theorem because it *is* the Pyghagorean theorem applied to circles.

Answer (score 2):

Suppose the center of the circle is (0,0) and $(x,y)$ is a point of the circle of radius $r$, $x^2+y^2=r^2$

The points $A=(0,0), B=(y,0), C=(x,y)$ define a rectangle triangle.

Comment: My teacher said that it follows from PT but it is not. How this is possible it looks just like PT...

Comment: It "follows from" the PT.  Well, that's something.  Okay, it's a formula for points on a circle whereas the PT is a formula about sides of a triangle so the are used in different circumstances so we can say they are different things.  But the are *equivalent* things in that one directly leads to the other and (if we were given the other by fiat) would lead directly to the first.  I would say she/he was *very* misleading to say they were "different".

Comment: Teachers sometimes like to split hairs.  The PT is a statement about lengths of sides of right triangles.  This is not literally **the same** as the statement "$x^2 + y^2 = r^2$ is the equation of a circle", though of course it is very closely related.  Pythagoras would not have understood "$x^2 + y^2 = r^2$ is the equation of a circle" (or its translation into ancient Greek) because algebra and analytic geometry had not yet been developed.  Once you have the concept of the equation of a curve, the two statements are essentially equivalent.

Comment: No, they are not literally the very same thing.  However, if I were a teacher I'd be freakin' *OVERJOYED* if one of my students was intelligent and clever enough to recognize that they were equivalent and related.  To *discourage* the student and tell him/her she/he is wrong is the absolute *LAST* thing I'd want to do.  And the OP didn't say he/she thought they *were* the same.  s/he noted they *looked* the same.  And they do!  Because they are equivalent and one is completely derived from the other.

Answer (score 0):

I can *NOT* believe you teacher said that!  Take a circle with radius r centered at (h,k).  Pick an arbitrary (x,y) on the circle.  Drop a vertical line down from (x,y) to (x, k).  Slide a horizontal line from (h,k) to (x,k).  These three points (x,y) to (x,k) to (h,k) back to (x,y) form a triangle.  Not just a triangle a right triangle.

So the triangle has base side A = (h,k) to (x,k).  It has length (x - h).

The triangle has height side B = (x,k) to (x, y).  It has length (y - k).

The triangle has hypothenuse C = (h,k) to (x,y). It has lenght r.

The pythagorean theorem says $A^2 + B^2 = C^2$ or $(x-h)^2 + (y - k)^2 = r^2$.  This gives us a formula for *any* point of the circle that relates the x value to its y value.

It is base *entirely* upon the Pythagorean Theorem.

Comment: It's possible to imagine a universe where they didn't prove the PT first but proved the circle formula first. (Not sure how they'd do that but it's conceivable.)  In such a universe we can use the circle formula to prove the pythogorean theorem but inscribing a right triangle into a circle where it's leg/hypotenuse vertex is the center and the hypotenuse is the radius.  From there the circle formula proves the PT.  In this sense we say the PT and the circle formula are "equivalent" because you can interchange one for the other and always come to the same system conclusions.

Answer (score 0):

When you write the equation of a circle, you start from a definition as:

> The locus of points $P$ that have the same distance $r$ from a fixed
>   point $C$ (the center).

Then you write the equation as $\overline PO=r$ using the standard definition of **(Pythagorean) distance** for points represented in an **orthogonal reference system**:
$$
\overline PO=\sqrt{(x_P-x_O)^2+(y_P-y_O)^2}=r
$$
and squaring you find the equation
$$
(x_P-x_O)^2+(y_P-y_O)^2=r^2
$$
Clearly, this seems the classical pythagorean formula, and a figure confirm that there is a rectangular triangle with $r$ as hypotenuse.
But note that this is a consequence of many other assumptions: the definition of the circle, the use of a particular distance, an the use of an orthogonal reference system.  And, finally, your equation refers to an infinite set of points $P$ not to a single triangle.

So, in my opinion, your teacher is right in inviting you to better think to the question and to the difference between a theorem and a consequence of this theorem.

In a different coordinate system, the equation of a circle can be very different, but the PT is always the same if the metric (the distance) is Pythagorean.